# Tensorflow Graph Execution Permission Denied Error

Tags: pyspark, virtualenv, tensorflow2.0, python-3.8

I have created a virtual environment which contains Tensorflow 2.11. I am using this virtual environment's python as spark driver and executor python. The venv zip has been added as an archive in PySpark. I am reading tf record files from s3 and created a tf dataset called `train_dataset`.

Calling `model.fit`:

```py
history = model.fit(
        train_dataset,
        epochs=epochs,
        steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
        validation_data=val_dataset,
        validation_steps=val_steps,
        callbacks=callbacks
    )
```

is throwing the below error:

```py
File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/home/hadoop/environment/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 52, in quick_execute

    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: 
Graph execution error:**


         [[{{node MultiDeviceIteratorGetNextFromShard}}]]
        [[RemoteCall]]
        [[IteratorGetNextAsOptional]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4621]
```

This is running on EMR serverless, I'm not sure why the permission error is popping up. Any suggestions/help is appreciated.